# Empty string in database

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have this table in my SQLDatabase:

```
CREATE TABLE Book(_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, Name TEXT NOT NULL)
```

Now my problem is that with this code no exception is thrown:

```
ContentValues args = new ContentValues();           
args.put("Name", "");

long id = db.insertOrThrow("Book", null, args);
```

I want that an exception is thrown if I try to put an empty string into the *Name* column. In the LogCat there is no exception too. What do I have to change in the table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An empty string is different from `NULL`, instead of throw an exception for empty strings, do a simple test and then execute whatever you would have in your `catch` block.